# Copy files(images) from file system to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm Working on image to extract some features, i need in the first steep to get data files(images) from the file system to HDFS.

What are the steps to flollow to do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- [google.com](http://google.com)

2- bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /source /destination

3- bin/hadoop fs -put /source /destination

4- bin/hadoop distcp /source /destination

5- [Apache Flume](http://flume.apache.org/)

6- HDFS API

7- MapReduce job to copy the files.

8- [Pig](http://pig.apache.org) script to copy the files.

You actually need some research on [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org) first.

Comment: source : path of the source files and destination ?? what i should do instead of destination(should be in hdfs)